System problem detected during ubuntu installation
I have two SSDs on my PC. I am using one for windows and wanted to use the other one for ubuntu. I followed the steps mentioned in the link https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview
Downloaded the 24.04 LTS and created the bootable usb drive
I selected the Erase disk option (The only thing i did differently is i did not go into advanced features). Everything goes smoothly but shortly after the installation begins the error message shows up saying "System problem detected". could my bootable drive be the issue or something else. My first option was to shrink my already existing ssd but it is not allocating me enough space so i went and bought a second ssd just for ubuntu. Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Did you verify the ISO you made the boot device from before making it? https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview

Have you updated UEFI & SSD firmware? Windows probably updates UEFI. While it should not matter when installing to separate drive, is Windows fast startup & bitlocker off? Or try manual install where you creatre gpt partitioning & add ESP -efi system partition as FAT32 and / (root) as ext4. If drive is large you may want separate /home or data partition(s).

I fixed it all I had to do was disable WIFI before starting installation.
